# cypress-testrail-reporter is not updating the result in testrail

Tags: cypress, testrail

I am trying to update the results of my testcases to testrail , and i tried to use the below options

```
reporter: "cypress-testrail-reporter",
  reporterOptions: {
    "host": "URL",
    "username": "name",
    "password": "api",
    "projectId": 82,
    "suiteId": 11092
  }
```

And as i given the proper name for my TC in my script as well
it("C305662 testcases",

But , i can see new testrun is getting created and it is added the testcases from suite , but result of the TC "C305662" is not getting updated after run.
I am not seeing any errors either

any inputs to fix

Comment: I am having a similar problem. Following the official guide, but it cannot see the suite, will only run if I set it to generate new suites and they then cannot find the cases because they are on an existing suite. The only option currently open to me is to generate a new instance of the case on every run. Not practical. I have a ticket with testrail support. This is their guide: https://support.gurock.com/hc/en-us/articles/7523391639956-Integrating-with-Cypress#01G75119Y2NVKTNND00MJ4YKPC